# non-type template parameter of user-defined type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, constexpr

I'm trying to define a template-class that has a non-type template parameter of a user-defined type. Unfortunately, without success so far. The real code is a bit too lengthy, but a simplified example looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class Maybe {
    bool is_ = false;
    T value_;

  public:
    constexpr Maybe() = default;
    constexpr Maybe(T value) : is_(true), value_(value) {}

    constexpr bool is() const { return is_; }
};

template <Maybe<int> parm>
struct Test {
    void say() const {
        std::cout << "parm is " << (parm.is() ? "set" : "not set") << ".\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    Test<Maybe<int>{}> not_set;
    Test<Maybe<int>(2)> is_set;

    not_set.say();
    is_set.say();
}
```

When I try to compile this code (with Clang 3.4) I get the following error message:

```
test.cc:15:22: error: a non-type template parameter cannot have type
      'Maybe<int>'
template <Maybe<int> parm>
                     ^
test.cc:23:10: error: value of type 'Maybe<int>' is not implicitly
      convertible to 'int'
    Test<Maybe<int>{}> not_set;
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cc:24:10: error: value of type 'Maybe<int>' is not implicitly
      convertible to 'int'
    Test<Maybe<int>(2)> is_set;
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
3 errors generated.
```

Now, I know that a non-type template parameter has to fulfill [some conditions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters). However, I thought that being [constexpr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) would be sufficient. Or can it really only be one of the built-in integral types?

Is there a way to pass non-type template parameters of my own user-defined type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this whole problem is the very reason why rational numbers are implemented as template-class with the actual numbers in the template parameters. to get a template-parameter storing more than just an int, you must create a similar class as `std::ratio` which also is evaluated at compile-time only.

as for your actual example, consider writing something similar to:

```
template<class T, T ... Params>
class Maybe {
```

and then

```
Test<Maybe<int,5> > is_set;
```

or

```
Test<Maybe<int> > not_set;
```

Comment: That's a really nice application of variadic templates. I was considering something of the form `template<class T, bool is=false, T value={}> class Maybe{};`. But your approach is much nicer.

Answer (score 8):

No, you cant.

n3376 14.1/7

> A non-type template-parameter shall not be declared to have floating
>   point, class, or void type.
>
> ```
> template<double d> class X; // error
> template<double* pd> class Y; // OK
> template<double& rd> class Z; // OK
> ```

so, you can pass pointer, or reference, but not object of class-type.

[live example](http://ideone.com/nvTwKd)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. Too bad that this isn't possible.

Answer (score 2):

In C++20, this is possible using *structural* literal class types:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct NullOptT {} NullOpt;

/**
 * Literal class type.
 *
 * Represents an optionally provided `int`.
 */
struct OptionalInt {
    constexpr OptionalInt(NullOptT) {}
    constexpr OptionalInt(int value): has_value(true), value(value) {}

    const bool has_value = false;
    const uint32_t value {};
};

/**
 * Prints whether or not a value was provided for "maybe" WITHOUT branching :)
 */
template<OptionalInt maybe>
void Print() {
    if constexpr(maybe.has_value) {
        std::cout << "Value is: " << maybe.value << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "No value." << std::endl;
    }
}

// Note: implicit conversions are at play!
int main()
{
    Print<123>();     // Prints "Value is: 123"
    Print<NullOpt>(); // Prints "No value."
}
```

I wrote up a blog post with more detail on the usage and restrictions of class literal NTTPs here: [Literal Classes as Non-type Template Parameters in C++20](https://blog.keha.dev/posts/cpp20-class-as-non-type-template-param/).

Answer (score 1):

I know that this question is old, but I would like  to point out a template meta programming approach to this.

In c++ you can pass any type to a template like that, so why not just make it a type?

In order to do that, you will want to make a wrapper class for your Maybe class:

```
template <typename T>
struct maybe_wrap 
{
    Maybe<T> value{};
}

template<typename T, T value>
struct maybe_wrap
{
    Maybe<T> value{value};
}
```

Then just pass the maybe_wrap as a typename and just access the `maybe_wrap<int, 3>().value` of it when you need it!

The only restriction of this is that T might not be one of the non-type values (int, bool, etc).

In that case, just use the above logic again!